# image greater than 2500px upload error. but some images more than 3300px uploading fine

Tags: wordpress, image, upload

I have the same issue on my website. I have two images and both resolutions are higher than 2500.
one image is 3300 and is png image and is uploading fine.
the other one is 7600 and is a jpg image and shows this error.
“Post-processing of the image failed. If this is a photo or a large image, please scale it down to 2500 pixels and upload it again.”
I tried all the methods but nothing works for me.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Can you please open the console ( right click + inspect element ). Upload the image again and if you receive any error messages. If you do not see anything in the console please head over the Network tab and do the same thing again. Please post any error messages here.

Comment: I get this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 ()

Comment: Do you use ModSecurity on your server by any chance ?

Comment: No, I don't use ModSecurity

Answer (score 0):

For me, I think the issue had something to do with imagick.

I solved it by running these commands:

```sh
sudo apt remove php-imagick
sudo service apache2 restart
```

You'll need GD installed since WordPress will default to that plugin for image processing.

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting the memory size from wp-config.php

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution that worked for me:

`sudo apt-get install php-mbstring`

`sudo service apache2 restart`

See this post there are many solutions for this: [Link](https://www.techify.club/2020/11/fix-post-processing-of-the-image-failed-wordpress-error-all-solutions/)